# How to hide and show images on thumbnail image click using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use javascript/jquery.

I have got below HTML where I want to work on "onclick" event of image link.

```
<div id="galleryContainer">
    <ul class="galleryThumbnails">
        <li><a href="/99/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/photo.aspx?item=media_616165_ID0EV&amp;menu=image_616165#mplayer_616165">
            <img width="70" height="56" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/thumb_616143_tcm481-616166.jpg"
                class="mpMenuItemSelected" id="thumb_616165_ID0EV" title="New Delhi Zoo" alt="New Delhi Zoo"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/99/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/photo.aspx?item=media_616165_ID0E3&amp;menu=image_616165#mplayer_616165">
            <img width="70" height="56" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/thumb_616146_tcm481-616168.jpg"
                class="mpMenuItemOff" id="thumb_616165_ID0E3" title="New Delhi Zoo" alt="New Delhi Zoo"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/99/english/destinations_offers/destinations/asiapacific/india/newdelhi/photo.aspx?item=media_616165_ID0EDB&amp;menu=image_616165#mplayer_616165">
            <img width="70" height="56" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/redfort_tcm481-616158.jpg"
                class="mpMenuItemOff" id="thumb_616165_ID0EDB" title="New Delhi RedFort" alt="New Delhi RedFort"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>       
        <div id="media_616165_ID0EV" class="galleryImage">
        <img width="390" height="312" alt="New Delhi Zoo" title="New Delhi Zoo" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/10894_tcm481-616143.jpg"></div>

    <div style="display: none;" id="media_616165_ID0E3" class="galleryImage">
        <img width="390" height="312" alt="New Delhi Zoo" title="New Delhi Zoo" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/deer_tcm481-616146.jpg"></div>

    <div style="display: none;" id="media_616165_ID0EDB" class="galleryImage">
        <img width="390" height="312" alt="New Delhi RedFort" title="New Delhi RedFort" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/redfort_tcm481-616157.jpg"></div>        
</div>
```

In above HTML, I have got thumbnail images ( please see the **UL**) for example

```
<img width="70" height="56" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/thumb_616143_tcm481-616166.jpg"
                class="mpMenuItemSelected" id="thumb_616165_ID0EV" title="New Delhi Zoo" alt="New Delhi Zoo">
```

Now I have got separate galleryImage div section for every thumbnail Image, which will show on the click on thumbnail image. For example to the above thumbnail there is

```
    <div id="media_616165_ID0EV" class="galleryImage">
<img width="390" height="312" alt="New Delhi Zoo" title="New Delhi Zoo" src="http://corp.com/99/english/images/10894_tcm481-616143.jpg"></div>
```

I want to hide and show the images according to the thumbnail is clicked.

**EDIT:**

I am having tab functionality as a link when first time the page is rendered the below @Rahul code works perfectly, however after navigating the any tab and again coming back it stops working the reason is that after coming back on same tab, my previous jquery code adds and extra div with same contents, below jquery get confused as my page now will be having same code twice. Please see the  example code when first time page is rendered.

```
<div class="tabs-container" id="tab-container">
top above html is rendered here
</div>
```

Now after navigating to other tab and coming back to same tab, now html on page is as below, the above mentioned code remain there in page with style="display: none;" an extra div is added to play the tab functionality:

```
<div class="tabs-container" id="tab-container" style="display: none;">
top above html is rendered here
</div>
<div id="divContenttab5" style="display: block;" class="dynDiv">
  <div class="tabs-container" id="tab-container">
      top above html is rendered here
</div>
</div>
```

Now the below Jquery stops working as there are same two type of htmls.

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MKS

Comment: DO check that there is no duplication of element ids.

Comment: @Rahul how can I check the duplication of element IDs as this is the part of code. please suggest for toggling the classes for image tag

Comment: You can have more than one element with the same id in a document. This will be invalid

Comment: Ok That is fixed can you please suggest how should I toggle the classes in above example for image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue with CSS class toggling, I changed the code given by @Rahul, please have a look and suggest for any changes.

```
$("#galleryContainer ul.galleryThumbnails li img").click(function () {
    var idArr = this.id.split('_');
    var divID = "media_" + idArr[1] + "_" + idArr[2];
    $("#galleryContainer ul.galleryThumbnails li img").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is('.mpMenuItemSelected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('mpMenuItemSelected');
            $(this).addClass('mpMenuItemOff');
        }
    });
    $("div.galleryImage").hide();
    $("#" + divID).show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
$("#galleryContainer ul.galleryThumbnails li img").click(function(){
    var idArr = this.id.split('_');
    var divID = "media_" + idArr[1] + "_" + idArr[2];

    $("div.galleryImage").hide();

    $("#" + divID).show();
});
```

If your HTML elements are dynamically generated then you can use this code which uses [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event.

```
$("#galleryContainer ul.galleryThumbnails li img").live("click", function(){
    var idArr = this.id.split('_');
    var divID = "media_" + idArr[1] + "_" + idArr[2];

    $("div.galleryImage").hide();

    $("#" + divID).show();
});
```

Comment: Many Thanks Rahul, But my issue is little more complicated, I have got tabs as links and when first time page is loaded above code works fine, but after the navigating any tab and coming back to same tab, it stops working. I know due to my tab functionality it is not working, I am editing my question according, kindly have a look and suggest!

Comment: Hi Rahul, please check the above edited code, if you see I have got a class in image tag by name 'mpMenuItemSelected' and 'mpMenuItemOff' which get toggled onclick event, please suggest as its still not working after using LIVE also.

Comment: Any suggestion for toggling the classes in img tag?

Comment: For toggling classes you can use `.toggleClass()` method

Answer (score 0):

When it is generated HTML it would be easy to add `onclick="myFunction('media_616165_ID0EV')"` to the thumbnails.

```
myFunction(media_id){
 $(media_id).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks can you please suggest how we can toggle with CSS in above image tag